# three.js program not showing anything but i think my codes right

Tags: javascript, three.js

im learning three.js and im trying to make a 3d showroom of a few planets i just made the moon, but for some reason all thats showing up is a plain black screen. heres my code so far: (updated version that still isnt working)

```
function main() {
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

    const fov = 35;
    const aspect = window.innerWidth / innerHeight;
    const near = 1;
    const far = 65536;
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);

    const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
    controls.update();

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
    light.position.set(50, 50, 50);
    scene.add(light);


     //moon
     const radius = 100;
     const xSegments = 50;
     const ySegments = 50;
     const geo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, xSegments, ySegments);

     function makeInstance(geo, color, x) {
        const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
        const moonMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, material);
        scene.add(moonMesh);

        moonMesh.position.x = x;

        return moonMesh
     }

     moon = makeInstance(geo, 0xffffff, 0);

     {
         const loader = new THREE.SphereTextureLoader();
         const texture = loader.load([
             'https://i.ibb.co/kgYT7L6/ea1d9797c9bf3dda7a23b238e5e4b364.jpg',
             'https://i.ibb.co/kgYT7L6/ea1d9797c9bf3dda7a23b238e5e4b364.jpg',
             'https://i.ibb.co/kgYT7L6/ea1d9797c9bf3dda7a23b238e5e4b364.jpg',
             'https://i.ibb.co/kgYT7L6/ea1d9797c9bf3dda7a23b238e5e4b364.jpg',
             'https://i.ibb.co/kgYT7L6/ea1d9797c9bf3dda7a23b238e5e4b364.jpg',
             'https://i.ibb.co/kgYT7L6/ea1d9797c9bf3dda7a23b238e5e4b364.jpg'
         ]);
         scene.background = texture;
     }

     function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
         const canvas = renderer.domElement;
         const width = canvas.clientWidth;
         const height = canvas.clientHeight;
         const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
         if (needResize) {
             renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
         }
         return needResize;
     }

    /* ignore this for now was just testing something
 function render(time) {
         time *= 0.001;

         if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
             const canvas = renderer.domElement;
             camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
             camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
         }

         moon.forEach((moonMesh, ndx) => {
             const speed = 0.5 + ndx * .1;
             const rot = time * speed;
             moonMesh.rotation.x = rot;
             moonMesh.rotation.y = rot;
         });*/
         renderer.render(scene, camera);

         requestAnimationFrame(render);
     }
     requestAnimationFrame(render);

     controls.addEventListener('change', render);
     window.addEventListener('resize', render);

     window.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
         e.preventDefault();
         window.focus();
     });
     window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
         e.preventDefault();
     });
}
main();
```

whenever i run it i just get a plain black screen with no errors or warnings. essentially im trying to make 3 planets next to one another but im just trying to do one right now but i cant figure it out.

heres my html as well if it helps:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <title> test2 </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test2.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="../lib/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/webgl-utils.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/webgl-debug.js"></script>

    <script src="test2.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Can you please make a minimum reproducible example on codesandbox.io or similar so we can see your code working?

Comment: @jered, asking for a working example on codesandbox.io suggests you couldn't understand the question from just what's in the question itself. If that's the case then by definition the question is off topic and you should vote to close it. Either that or ask for a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 2):

`MeshPhongMaterial` needs a light to be seen.  I don't understand what you're trying to do with the `light = {}` object, but it's not going to illuminate anything. If you're trying to mimic a star, perhaps you'd like to add an actual [`THREE.PointLight` object](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/PointLight) to your scene. Although I'd start with an `AmbientLight` first to test your objects are in the right position.

As far as your star background, the stars are very tiny 1px dots, which are blending into blackness when scaled down. This is exactly what they look like when added to this answer:
[image]

I recommend you use a starry background with more features, like the Milky Way for instance.

Comment: i've fixed the light but still nothing is showing just a black screen

Comment: @hkokay Sorry, that's the best I can do with the code you posted. Could be any of dozens of issues. You should consider adding a working [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) Are you sure you added the renderer's DOMElement to the HTML page?

Comment: i updated with my html and my updated version of my code if you can check it out again

Answer (score 1):

4 issues at least

1. No idea what a `SphereTextureLoader` is. That's not a three.js thing AFAIK? Maybe you meant `CubeTextureLoader`?
2. Using `CubeTextureLoader` your textures are not square. Cubemap textures are required to be square. I replaced them with square cubemap textures.
3. The Camera is at 0,0,0 and the sphere is at 0,0,0 so the camera is inside the sphere. I moved the camera out
4. The light at 50, 50, 50, but the sphere had a radius of 100 so the light is inside the sphere

Fixing all those things it works for me

```js
function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas
  });

  const fov = 35;
  const aspect = window.innerWidth / innerHeight;
  const near = 1;
  const far = 65536;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
// move the camera await from the center
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 1000);

  const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
  controls.update();

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
// move the light outside the moon
  light.position.set(50, 50, 150);
  scene.add(light);


  //moon
  const radius = 100;
  const xSegments = 50;
  const ySegments = 50;
  const geo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, xSegments, ySegments);

  function makeInstance(geo, color, x) {
    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
    const moonMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, material);
    scene.add(moonMesh);

    moonMesh.position.x = x;

    return moonMesh
  }

  const moon = makeInstance(geo, 0xffffff, 0);

  {
// use CubeTextureLoader not SphereTextureLoader (no idea what SphereTextureLoader is)
    const loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
    const texture = loader.load([
// use square textures as required for a cubemap
        'https://webglsamples.org/spacerocks/assets/space_rt.jpg',
        'https://webglsamples.org/spacerocks/assets/space_lf.jpg',
        'https://webglsamples.org/spacerocks/assets/space_up.jpg',
        'https://webglsamples.org/spacerocks/assets/space_dn.jpg',
        'https://webglsamples.org/spacerocks/assets/space_fr.jpg',
        'https://webglsamples.org/spacerocks/assets/space_bk.jpg',
   /*
      'https://i.ibb.co/kgYT7L6/ea1d9797c9bf3dda7a23b238e5e4b364.jpg',
      'https://i.ibb.co/kgYT7L6/ea1d9797c9bf3dda7a23b238e5e4b364.jpg',
      'https://i.ibb.co/kgYT7L6/ea1d9797c9bf3dda7a23b238e5e4b364.jpg',
      'https://i.ibb.co/kgYT7L6/ea1d9797c9bf3dda7a23b238e5e4b364.jpg',
      'https://i.ibb.co/kgYT7L6/ea1d9797c9bf3dda7a23b238e5e4b364.jpg',
      'https://i.ibb.co/kgYT7L6/ea1d9797c9bf3dda7a23b238e5e4b364.jpg'
   */
    ]);
    scene.background = texture;
  }

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    /* ignore this for now was just testing something
    moon.forEach((moonMesh, ndx) => {
      const speed = 0.5 + ndx * .1;
      const rot = time * speed;
      moonMesh.rotation.x = rot;
      moonMesh.rotation.y = rot;
    });
    */
    
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  controls.addEventListener('change', render);
  window.addEventListener('resize', render);

  window.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.focus();
  });
  window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
main();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```